# Multiple Page App Side Bar Icon and Background in Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

1. Is there any way to use the icons which ı select for the sidebar in multiple page app. I want to make a sidebar like the below image:
2. Is there any way to change the background image of sidebar?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rename the pages starting with a number, the icon and then the page name. Streamlit will automatically take care of the numbers and the `_` by removing them leaving only the icon and the page name. Pages are sorted based on the numbers.

Your page should return only>>>  Mapping Demo

```
# How to name page:

1__Mapping_Demo.py
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I suggest to keep it simple and use Jamiu Shaibu's answer, **BUT** if you don't want to / can't change your scripts file names:

You can use [this hacky solution](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/a-few-questions-about-multi-page-applications/27584/2?u=mordor1110) at the top of your main file.

Asumming your main script file name is `main.py`:

```
workdir/
   + main.py
   + mapping_demo.py
   + ploting_demo.py
```

```
# main.py
pages = st.source_util.get_pages('main.py')
new_page_names = {
  'mapping_demo': ' Mapping Demo',
  'ploting_demo': ' Ploting demo',
}

for key, page in pages.items():
  if page['page_name'] in new_page_names:
    page['page_name'] = new_page_names[page['page_name']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<img src="path/to/pngimage.png"/>` and use PNG images to get the result

Answer (score 0):

For second question:

```
st.markdown('<style>div[class="css-zbg2rx e1fqkh3o1"] {color:black; background: url("url adress");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size:350%;} </style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
```