# Streamit multipage app saving script with emoji

Tags: streamlit, multipage, multi-page-application

I'm sure this is simple but i'm stuck.

Been able to develope an app following:

https://blog.streamlit.io/introducing-multipage-apps/

Except for being able to save the pages with an emoji for instance '01__main_page.py'

When I try i get:

[image]

Can someone please advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to [Multiple Page App Side Bar Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73678673/19290081)

Comment: Hi, thank you. Reading the page that looks exactly what I'm doing renaming the file '01__main_page.py' as per the example in the notes but it doesn't like it.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Regarding "Except for being able to save the pages". Can you give a detailed example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi using windows. I'm trying to save the .py file as '01__main_page.py' so that the emoji shows up on the left hand side with the balloon emoji. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show a code that you have tried that did not work?

Comment: Hi, it's literally this last part of the link in the original post: "You can also add emojis! Try renaming the script files to:

01__main_page.py

pages/02__page2.py

• pages/03__page3.py"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was saving my script to a shared drive in my workplace. I think it was a setting in the shared drive that did not permit emojis in filenames. When I moved the script to the local hard drive the problem resolved (though I think the implementation of emojis within the filename is distinctly suboptimal).

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sounds like that's the problem I have. Many thanks will try the C drive.